# Ejecutar un UPDATE SQL copiando un campo

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, linux, mariadb

mi pregunta es la siguiente:

Quiero hacer un update a una tabla pero un campo se debe mover y no lo logro..

ejemplo:

Tengo la consulta `SELECT * FROM vehiculos` y su resultado es:

```
id |  marca   | val_actual | Val_anterior |

1  |  audi    |     100    |      0       |
2  |  mazda   |     100    |      0       |
```

Y ejecuto la siguiente Consulta:

```
UPDATE 
  productos 
SET
  val_actual = 300,
  val_anterior = val_actual
WHERE
  marca = 'audi',
  AND val_anterior != 0
  AND id = id;
```

**PERO: lo que obtengo es lo siguiente:**

```
id |  marca   | val_actual | Val_anterior |

1  |  audi    |     300    |     300      |
2  |  mazda   |     100    |      0       |
```

**Y LO QUE QUIERO OBTENER ES ESTO:**

```
id |  marca   | val_actual | Val_anterior |

1  |  audi    |     300    |     100      |
2  |  mazda   |     100    |      0       |
```

Ojalá alguien pudiere ayudarme, es un ejemplo simple, lo que quiero es copiar un campo a otro, y actualizar el registro antigüo.

Puse lo de los carros porque es lo más fácil de entender.

Comment: No se entiende bien. ¿Según lo que muestras, el `100` que es `val_actual` en la fila `2` debe pasar a ser el `val_anterior` en la fila `1`?

Comment: @A.Cedano, No, quiero que el 100 de la columna 3 fila 1, pase a a la columna 4 de esa misma fila, si hay mas audis, hará lo mismo para cada uno de ellos... por eso tiene el id=id

Comment: ¿No funciona como indica @FranciscoGarrido?

Comment: @A.Cedano Si funciona a la perfección gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplemente asigna el valor anterior antes de cambiar, si lo asignas después de cambiarlo... Pues tendrás el mismo valor.

```
UPDATE 
  productos 
SET
  val_anterior = val_actual,
  val_actual = 300  
WHERE
  marca = 'audi',
  AND val_anterior != 0
  AND id = id;
```

Comment: Funciona!! gracias amigo. No sabía que ese orden podría afectar.